# Transactions are failing as table is Locked in ORACLE

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, transactions

I do have a below scenario in a legacy codebase -
 `'Team'` table holds information about Team and a counter. It has a column named `'TEAM_NAME'` and `'COUNTER'`.
Below 3 step operation is being executed in a transaction -

- Take a exclusive `LOCK` on table.
- Read the counter corresponding to the team.
- Use that counter and increment the counter value & save it back to TEAM table.

Once these steps are performed , Commit the complete operation.
Due to taking an Exclusive LOCK on table in the first step other concurrent transactions are failing. I want to perform this without loosing transactions in the system.
I do think that if i remove `LOCK` statement and have my method as `Synchronized` can work but i do have 4 JVMs in real time and still concurrent transaction can hit this.
Please suggest some better design way to handle this.

Comment: Team table is a shared resource in your case which needs to be locked. Using Synchronized will only lock at JVM level and will not lock shared resource. What do you mean by other transactions failing? Are they not making blocking select call on team table so that they wait instead of failing?
Also, you can think about Row level lock instead of locking entire table, that way only  other rows (teams) can be deited

Comment: I would use a `select...for update...` on the row being updated instead of a table-level lock.

Answer (score 0):

You should almost never need to do a manual `LOCK` in Oracle. If you're doing that, you should probably rethink what you are doing. What you should probably be doing is:

1. Do `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` on your table corresponding to the team. This will lock only that row, not the entire table. Concurrent sessions working on different teams will be free to continue.
2. Do whatever you need to do.
3. Run an `UPDATE ...` to update the counter.

An even simpler way would be:

1. Do `UPDATE ... RETURNING my_counter INTO ...` which will return the updated value of the counter.
2. Do what you need to do, keeping in mind you have the incremented counter value.